# A simple way to substitute IDs for strings in a view

Tags: c++, qt, model-view-controller, tableview

I am storing service names outside of `services` table. So `services` table contains everything I need in a tableView except that I'd like to show service names stored in `service_types` in the view.
As far as I understood, there is no way to make `QSqlTableModel` work with even a simplest join.

I know I'm supposed to inherit `QAbstractTableModel`, but I have no idea how to implement anything there. A wizard in Qt Creator made a `.h/.cpp` pair for me, but I can't find any examples on the internet to get an idea what am I supposed to be implementing.

So, I'm asking if there is any clever way to get all service types strings (there are just 200) into a QMap beforehand, and just make tableView display them instead of IDs.

Comment: maybe, I can inherit QSqlTableModel itself, and just make `data()` method behave differently (for 1 column)?

Comment: Qt documentation is quite complete. See http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#model-classes for an explanation of how it works and http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/examples-itemviews.html for examples.

Comment: You have to subclass your model and in the `data()` function substitute original data with one you query from another table.

Comment: @vahancho good idea. What do I write in re-implementation? Like, let's say I'm reimplementing data method. I have an `if()` for determining the column. But what to write outside of it? What is the code equivalent of `just leave as is`? I mean, you can't use this->index(r,c)->data() method, while defining it, can you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment, you can subclass your `QSqlTableModel` model and in the `data()` function substitute original data with one you query from another table. E.g.:

```
QVariant MyTableModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
  if (index.column() == 0 /*first column*/ && role == Qt::DisplayRole)
  {
    // Query data from another table (service_types) and as you get the right
    // type for the given row, return it.
    return type_I_got_from_service_type_table;
  }
  return QSqlTableModel::data(index, role);
}
```